# Irreducible component of a scheme over a dvr

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $\mathcal M$ be a (reduced) quasi-projective scheme over a dvr (of mixed caracteristics), $R$. Suppose that the generic fiber $\mathcal M_{\eta_R}$ is (nonempty) smooth and irreducible of dimension $n>0$ and that the special fiber $\mathcal M_{x}$ is (nonempty) smooth of dimension $n$ also. Can one find a irreducible component $\mathcal M'\subset \mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M'_{\eta_R}$ contains an nonempty open subscheme of $\mathcal M_{\eta_R}$ and $\mathcal M'_x$ contains also an nonempty open subscheme of $\mathcal M_x$.

Comment: Currently, what is stopping $\mathcal{M}$ being the disjoint union of some random smooth irred scheme on the generic fibre and some other random smooth irred scheme on the special fibre? This is reduced and quasi-proj, and any component is concentrated in one fibre.

Comment: Surely you meant to say "non-empty open subscheme" twice in the final sentence. If you don't assume $\mathcal{M}$ is $R$-flat then the answer is "no" as slider says. If $\mathcal{M}$ is $R$-flat then it is irreducible due to irreducibility of its generic fiber (as its generic points must lie in the generic fiber, by going-down for flatness), so the only choice of $\mathcal{M}'$ is $\mathcal{M}$ and this certainly works. If you provide some motivation it may clarify if you meant to ask something else.

Comment: Thank you both. My intuition is that the randomly built situation cannot happen: $\mathcal M$ is a moduli space of (stable) vector bundles on  $\mathfrak X$ (intregral) and we have a smooth projective morphism $\mathfrak X \rightarrow Spec(R)$. And we know that we have a local (for fppf topology) a universal bundle.